# Cannot embed YouTube video in PowerPoint 2010

Tags: video, microsoft-powerpoint, youtube

I'm trying to embed a YouTube video in a PowerPoint 2010 presentation on 32 bit Windows 7 Professional.  I've followed the Microsoft directions to pick the "Use old embed code" option on YouTube, and the embed code that is generated looks well-formed.  However, every time I try to embed the video, I get this error:

"PowerPoint cannot insert a video from this embed code.  Verify that the embed code is correct, and then try again."

Has anyone else dealt with this successfully?

Comment: Briefly, yes.  But then YouTube changed the way they want the embed code to work.  They did this several times, after which MS decided to stop chasing them and has removed the feature from at least some versions of PPT.  An update might, in fact, remove it from your copy of 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Rather than click 'embed code' at the bottom/side of a youtube video, you simply hover over the video, right click and select 'copy embed html'. Paste that code in to the 'insert video from web site' option within PowerPoint and you're a winner!